# R: How to read and combine tables with different formats?

Tags: r, dataframe, format, readlines

**Issue**

I have extracted some tables from URLs and combined them. Each URL represent an ID. The combined data frame is not structured correctly because table formats differ between IDs.

Examples of table structures:

https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1000097/0000919574-13-001835.txt # Uses "," as thousand separator
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1001085/0001193125-13-060806.txt # Does not use a thousand separator

**Code**

The code used to extract the tables (credits to Limey for original code):

```
all <-data.frame()

for (i in 1:nrow(URL_file)) {
  skip_to_next <- FALSE
  
  tryCatch({
    # Read the text files from the web
    fileContents <- readr::read_file(URL_file$link[i])
    # Extract the tables.  The regex isn't quite right, as it includes the starting <TABLE>
    # and ending </TABLE> tags, but more complicated regexes failed.
    tables <- stringr::str_extract_all(
      fileContents,
      stringr::regex(
        "(?s)<TABLE>(.*?)</TABLE>",
        multiline = TRUE,
        dotall = TRUE
      )
    )
    
    # Function to process a single tibble
    toTibble <- function(y) {
      lines <- str_split_fixed(y, "\n", n = Inf)
      colStarts <- c()
      colEnds <- c()
      # Scroll through to final table header
      for (i in 1:(length(lines) - 1)) {
        # Final line is '</TABLE>' because of initial regex
        # Could probably to this with regexes, but my head is hurting
        
        if (any(!is.na(stringr::str_locate(lines[i], "<\\w>")))) {
          # Define column widths based on locations of type markers.  THIS IS AN ASSUMPTION
          colStarts <-
            stringr::str_locate_all(lines[i], "<\\w>")[[1]][, "start"]
          
          for (i in 1:(length(colStarts) - 1))
            colEnds[i] <- colStarts[i + 1] - 1
          colEnds[length(colStarts)] <- stringr::str_length(lines[i])
          lines <- lines[(i + 1):(length(lines) - 1)]
          data <- dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(
            lines,
            # For each data line
            function(line)
              tibble::enframe(# Split in to columns and convert to a tibble of name/value pairs
                stringr::str_trim(
                  stringr::str_sub(line,
                                   colStarts,
                                   colEnds)
                )) %>%                  # Convert from name/value pairs to columns
              tidyr::pivot_wider(
                values_from = "value",
                names_from = "name",
                names_prefix = "Column"
              )
          ))
          # Finished
          return(data)
        }
      }
    }
    
    alldata <- bind_rows(lapply(tables[[1]], function(t)
      toTibble(t)))
    
    if (nrow(alldata) > 0) {
      alldata$ID <- URL_file$ID[i]
    }
    
    #alldata$ID <- URL_file$ID[i]
    
    all <- bind_rows(all, alldata)
    
    print(i) #print every 10th value to monitor progress of the loop
    
  }, error = function(e) {
    skip_to_next <<- TRUE
  })
  
  if (skip_to_next) {
    next
  }
}
```

**Examples**

This is an example of the input tables (one row row from each of the above URLs) - and this is also the ideal structure of the output.

```
+-----------+-------------------------+----------------+-----------+--------------+-----------------+--------+----------+-----------------------+-------------+---------+--------+-------+
|   (ID)    |     NAME OF ISSUER      | TITLE OF CLASS |   CUSIP   | VALUE(x1000) | SHRS OR PRN AMT | SH/PRN | PUT/CALL | INVESTMENT DISCRETION | OTHER MNGRS |  SOLE   | SHARED | NONE  |
+-----------+-------------------------+----------------+-----------+--------------+-----------------+--------+----------+-----------------------+-------------+---------+--------+-------+
| (1000097) | ABERCROMBIE & FITCH     | CL A           | 002896207 |        4,797 |         100,000 | SHS    |          | Shared-Defined        | 1/2/3       | 100,000 |        |       |
| (1001085) | AMERICAN TOWER CORP NEW | COM            | 03027X100 |        96566 |         1249724 | SH     |          | Defined               | 1           | 1170124 |      0 | 79600 |
+-----------+-------------------------+----------------+-----------+--------------+-----------------+--------+----------+-----------------------+-------------+---------+--------+-------+
```

The current data format is a comma-separated csv file:

```
ABERCROMBIE & FITCH,CL A,002896207,4,797,100,000,SHS,,Shared-Defined,1/2/3,100,000,,,1000097,NA,NA,NA,
AMERICAN TOWER CORP NEW,COM,03027X100,96566,1249724,SH,,Defined,1,1170124,0,,1001085,NA,NA,NA
```

One of the primary issues is that the output is a comma-separated file, and some of the numbers are thousand separated by a "," too. The extra "," make the rows of unequal length.

**Thoughts and approaches**

I have found some potential approaches to the the issue:

- I thought this might be a fixed-width (input) file, but I couldn't use this to an advantage.
- Functions like fread etc. offer great flexibility.
- Readlines could be useful here. I read a guide (https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/de_Jonge+van_der_Loo-Introduction_to_data_cleaning_with_R.pdf), and the part on p. 15 seems relevant, but I can't make it work.

Is there a way to structure the data to my desired output? Or do I have to extract the tables another way? if so, how can I change the above code to better fit my objectives?

Comment: `readr::read_table()` seems to be able to read your tables perfectly, provided you give it the right `skip = ...` value. Maybe you could use that in your code?

Comment: The tables in the URLs start at different lines, so the "skip" would have to be dynamic. Further, can I use read_table when some of the URLs contain several tables (such as this one: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1000275/0001140361-13-007449.txt)?

Comment: You are right, I was thinking you could write some code to identify where the tables are (as you have already done), and then read them with the correct `skip` value. I haven't tested it, but I think that should also work for multiple tables.